How to see that $n_0:=\left\lfloor\frac{a-\varphi}{\pi}\right\rfloor\geq 0$ and that $x_0$ is the smallest possible extreme point possible?
Consider
$$
f(x):=A\cdot e^{-kx}\sin(\omega x+\varphi)
$$
with $A,k,\omega,\varphi>0$ and $x\geq 0$.
Then, we have
$$
f'(x)=A\cdot e^{-kx}(\omega\cos(\omega x+\varphi)-k\sin(\omega x+\varphi)).
$$
Particularly,
$$
\begin{align*}
f'(x)=0&\Leftrightarrow\omega\cos(\omega x+\varphi)-k\sin(\omega x+\varphi)=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow\tan(\omega x+\varphi)=\frac{\omega}{k}\\
&\Leftrightarrow\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}:~\omega x+\varphi=\arctan(\omega/k)+n\pi\\
&\Leftrightarrow\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}:~x=\frac{1}{\omega}(a+n\pi-\varphi), \textrm{ where }0<a:=\arctan(\omega/k)<\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&\qquad \textrm{and }a+n\pi-\varphi\geq 0, \textrm{ i.e. }n\geq\frac{\varphi-a}{\pi}.
\end{align*}
$$
So this gives the candidates for extreme points of $f$.
Now, it is said that, setting
$$
n_0:=\left\lfloor\frac{a-\varphi}{\pi}\right\rfloor\qquad\textrm{(Gauß bracket)}
$$
one has that $n_0\geq 0$ and
$$
x_0:=\frac{1}{\omega}(a-n_0\pi-\varphi)
$$
is the smallest possible extreme point which can occur.
I do not understand why $n_0\geq 0$ and why $x_0$ is the smallest possible extreme point.
More generally, I also do not understand why this Gauß bracket is considered at all, and why not
$$
N_0:=\left\lceil\frac{\varphi-a}{\pi}\right\rceil=\min\{n\in\mathbb{Z}: n\geq \frac{\varphi -a}{\pi}\}?
$$
I think in the end, this is exactly what is used since in the definition of $x_0$ we have the term $-n_0$ appearing and
$$
-n_0=N_0.
$$
But it remains unclear to me why $n_0\geq 0$ (respectively, $N_0\leq 0$) and why the sign is important.
Could you please explain that to me?

What is your reference? Is it a part of a proof of some bigger result? We can't really try to understand the author's intent (speaking about the importance of the sign) if we don't have much context to go off of. As for the sign itself, I think it's the opposite, $n_0$ is negative because $a$ is strictly smaller than $\pi$ and $\varphi$ is positive thus $$\frac{a - \varphi}{\pi} < \frac{a}{\pi} < 1$$

Its from a German textbook, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-60813-5, page 219. I took a look in the latest edition, it still claims that $n_0\geq 0$. It is just taken from a section where the aim is to discuss the function and to draw its graph. I also tend to think that's a typo and it should be $-n_0\geq 0$.


I do not understand why $n_0\ge 0$

I agree with you. Whereas we have $0<a<\frac{\pi}2$, no upper bound for $\varphi$ is given,
so it can be that $\varphi>a$ and then $n_0<0$.

why $x_0$ is the smallest possible extreme point.

This is because to provide such a point we have to find the biggest integer $m=-n$ such that $a-m\pi-\varphi\ge 0$, that is $\frac{a-\varphi}{\pi}-m\ge 0$. So the required $m$ is exactly $\lfloor \frac{a-\varphi}{\pi}\rfloor$, by the definition of $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$

why this Gauß bracket is considered at all, and why not
$$
N_0:=\left\lceil\frac{\varphi-a}{\pi}\right\rceil=\min\{n\in\mathbb{Z}: n\geq \frac{\varphi -a}{\pi}\}?
$$

Since $-\lfloor t\rfloor=\lceil -t\rceil$ for each real $t$, anyway $N_0=-n_0$.
So $$x_0:=\frac{1}{\omega}(a-n_0\pi-\varphi)=\frac{1}{\omega}(a+N\pi-\varphi)$$

why the sign is important.

So I think that the sign is unimportant, but is a feature of the author(s) solution approach, maybe, the author(s) prefer(s) to deal with $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ rather than with $\lceil\cdot\rceil$.

Isn't it $-\lfloor t\rfloor=\lceil -t\rceil$?

@selector Yes, of course, corrected. Sorry for the misprint and thank you for the attention.
